# This question about Rise of Skywalker Bingo should be reopened

Tags: discussion

Heck, it shouldn't have been closed to begin with.

[Which predictions of The Rise of Skywalker: Darths & Droids Bingo were correct?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224484/which-predictions-of-the-rise-of-skywalker-darths-droids-bingo-were-correct)

I don't see any logic in it, sorry. There are two other questions like that which have been well received. There are plenty of questions about identity hundreds of things in a picture which are way broader than this. And anyway it's a finite list of items.

Last but not least, it's been posted a day after the movie release. It shouldn't be reminded, but this network is far from being dedicated to USA.

Comment: The question was asked _before_ the film was released and so was closed per the future works policy. As far as I am aware the film hadn't released anywhere on the 16th but I may be wrong.

Comment: It should be reopened now of course but that was why it was closed initially.

Answer (score 5):

The question is not too broad and no longer about a future work which is why it was closed in the first place.

It has been reopened.